# What's the deal with Dr. Ailat?

Tags: star-trek

Dr. Ailat was mentioned many times as the CMO of the USS Stargazer in The Autobiography of Jean-Luc Picard, but he doesn't even have a Memory Alpha page. What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Portal:Main) is the wiki for Star Trek canon as shown in the television series and movies, wherein Dr. Ailat has not been mentioned, and thus not established as canon.

[Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) is devoted to the wider Star Trek extended canon as found, additionally, in licenced printed works, video games, and so on. While this character doesn't appear to have an entry there either, it would be the logical place to find or write one.

Comment: The Autobiography of Jean-Luc Picard itself has a Memory Alpha page, that's the only reason I pointed out Memory Alpha. http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Autobiography_of_Jean-Luc_Picard . That implies that it is canon, thus Dr. Ailat is.

Comment: Most, if not all, of the licenced Star Trek subsidiary works have articles on Memory Alpha. Their *contents*, however, are not generally given the encyclopedic treatment that plot elements from screen works are given, except under the heading *apocrypha*, which is to say, the opposite of canon.

Comment: Additionally, most of the novels has a character named [Carter Greyhorse](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Carter_Greyhorse) as Stargazer's CMO. Not yet having read the autobiography, I don't have a ready explanation for the disparity, though I have a reasonable suspicion that it is one of the many unresolved continuity conflicts which exist in Star Trek's vast expanded canon.